# Unbounded spectrum can be empty

Tags: functional-analysis

Can someone please provide an example of a Hilbert space $H$ together with a (prefer densely defined if possible) unbounded operator $T$ such that $\sigma(T)$ is the empty set?

I have tried to use the analytic method, to no success.  And then I read on wikipedia that it may be empty, but unfortunately no citation.

Comment: Have you thought about the shift operator, T(a_0, a_1 ...)=(0,a_0 ...)$

Comment: @ReneSchipperus you must mean to play with the domain because it's bounded, so the only fudging can be with the domain.  Could you perhaps elaborate on what you're getting at here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let $X = L^{2}[0,1]$. Let $A=\frac{d}{dx}$ on the domain $\mathcal{D}(A)$ consisting of absolutely continuous functions $f : [0,1] \rightarrow \mathbb{C}$ such that $f(0)=0$. The domain of $A$ is dense in $X$. For any $\lambda \in \mathbb{C}$, and for any $g \in X$, there is a unique $f \in \mathcal{D}(A)$ such that
$$
                       (A-\lambda I)f = g.
$$
The solution is
$$
             f(t) = e^{\lambda t}\int_{0}^{t}e^{-\lambda s}g(s)\,ds.
$$
So the resolvent $R(\lambda)=(A-\lambda I)^{-1}$ exists for all $\lambda \in \mathbb{C}$ because the $(A-\lambda I)^{-1}$ is a bounded operator on $X$. That is, $\sigma(A)=\emptyset$. Remove the condition $f(0)=0$ from the domain and you get an operator $B$ for which $\sigma(B)=\mathbb{C}$ because $e^{\lambda t} \in \mathcal{N}(B-\lambda I)$ for every $\lambda \in \mathbb{C}$.